# I am trying to send a private message to everyone in a discord channel if they have a certain role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

HI i mannged to find this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Pong")

@bot.command()
async def message_role(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
    for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await bot.send_message(member, message)



# Eventsd
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='I am Nice'))
    print('Der bot {0.user} ist Gestartet'.format(bot))
```

If i Type .message_role NewTest Hi nothing happens
and if i Type !message_role NewTest Hi i get the command not find error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You're defining both client and bot, you only use one
2. You didn't enable `intents.members`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents
```

Also make sure to enable privileged intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), [here's](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents#privileged-intents) how

Wherever you're using `client` change it to bot

```py
@bot.command()
async def message_role(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
    for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await bot.send_message(member, message)
```

Instead of `bot.send_message` it's `member.send`

```py
await member.send(message)
```

Also a here's a better way of writing your code

```py
@bot.command()
async def message_role(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
    for member in role.members:
        await member.send(message)
```

Comment: Ok now i am getting: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message' Also new Code is Updatet to what you said i should add.

Comment: I think the error pretty much speaks for itself, but I edited my answer. Remember to accept it if it helped

Comment: Much much Love from me to you it worked ^^